# generating AST from existing python function

Tags: python

I'm trying to use python's `ast.parse` to generate the AST of a function I defined, but the `parse` function takes in strings as parameter. How can I use it on a function / code object that is defined in the same file? For instance:

```
def foo(bar):
  print(bar)

import ast
ast.parse(foo) # this doesn't work
```

Comment: You could maybe [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) it but what's the _context_ - why do you need the AST?

Comment: Duplicate? [get the abstract syntax tree of imported function?](/q/4812144/4518341)

Comment: AST works with source code. Once you have the function in the variable `foo` it has already been compiled to byte code, there's no source code available.